# Using MongoDB with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, repository, crud, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to implement mongodb in MVC Web Api following the steps as in [***Using MongoDB with ASP.NET Web API***](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/19/using-web-api-with-mongodb.aspx) 
I am stuck at "Implementing the Repository" where do i put the 2 block of codes under the heading? I created a class ContactRepository as follows:

```
public class ContactRepository : IContactRepository
{

}
```

But it shows error when i put those two block of codes under the heading "Implementing the Repository".

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented recently but using PHP & Doctrine ORM for Mongo. I did something like this for it

```
/** @Entity(repositoryClass="Doctrine\Blog\ORM\BlogPostRepository") */
class BlogPost
{
/** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
  private $id;

/** @Column(type="string") */
  private $title;

/** @Column(type="text") */
  private $body;

// ...
}
```

Can u do with using annotations?